# Bootstrap Grid Overflow Center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the Bootstrap Grid I have made row with 11 logos. Each of the 11 have the class="col-md-2 col-xs-4", meaning 2 rows for "md" and 4 rows for "xs".

Is it even possible to center the final row? Am I misunderstanding the grid?

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can use [offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).
Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

[image: responsive layout]

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/r98pj2s8/

```css
.logos img {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.logos .row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container logos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/c69/f9c/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/9c6/cf9/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/69c/9cf/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/3cc/6ff/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/c69/f9c/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/9c6/cf9/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/69c/9cf/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/3cc/6ff/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/c69/f9c/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-offset-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/9c6/cf9/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2"><img src="//placehold.it/80x80/69c/9cf/?text=logo" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really clear and furthermore very pretty. Upvoted :)